# Graphs backround on Iexplorer after Deploying it on the server

Tags: highcharts

Hi all and thanks for your time,
i having a really weird problem: when i'm debuging the graphs on chrome and Iexplorer on visualstudio 2012 everything is ok but the weird problem happening after i'm deploying the project on the IIS, when i'm trying to browse the site with the graphs from chrome it works fine but when i'm trying to browse the site with any Iexplorer version the background of the graphs appear with black instead of transparent like i defined it, did you encounter the same?

i'm using iis 7 and the new version of the Highcharts.
![enter image description here][1]

`chart: {
       backgroundColor: "transparent",
       type: 'line'
       }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `'rgba(255,255,255,0)'` instead of "transparent".